# perl Disable "Setting locale failed." warning to display on screen

Tags: perl

I want to disable locale setting failed warnings to get displayed on the command line.

In system(aix) available locale are
    C, POSIX, en_US.8859-15, en_US.ISO8859-1, en_US

The language which is set is "EN_US"(export $LANG=EN_US), which is not available in the above list.
Because of this execution of the below command is throwing warnings.
if language is set from above list(export $LANG=en_US), it's working fine.

---

```
#  perl -X -e "print 'hello'"
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
        LC_ALL = (unset),
        LC__FASTMSG = "true",
        LANG = "EN_US"
     are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C")
```

### hello

The same command i have kept in perl script and it is throwing the same warnings.
I have also used the `$SIG(__WARN__)`, but the above warnings are not getting catch here. But the other warning related to undeclared variable etc are getting catch.
One solution is to install the unavailable locale that i'm aware, but looking for to disable this since my code have logic to select other language messages.

So what is the way to disable these warnings on the screen?

Comment: Because `EN_US` doesn't exist, it's treated as `C`. So either use `export $LANG=C` to maintain the current behaviour, or fix the misspelling of `en_US`.

Comment: `EN_US` is an AIX-ish term for `en_US.UTF-8`. As it is not installed, there is no point in using it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could set the `PERL_BADLANG` environmental variable to ignore these warnings as documented in [perldoc perllocale #Temporarily Fixing Locale Problems](https://perldoc.perl.org/perllocale.html#Temporarily-fixing-locale-problems)

```
LANG="FOO" perl -X -e 'print "hello\n";'
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LANG = "FOO"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
hello
```

**vs**

```
PERL_BADLANG=0 LANG="FOO" perl -X -e 'print "hello\n";'
hello
```